# Passing Constant String Value to Register

Tags: assembly, x86, bootloader, gnu-assembler, xv6

I am rewriting the boot sector for the xv6 OS as an assignment and am attempting to execute a simple frame that does not output correctly to QEMU.

This is using the QEMU simulator (system i386) with the Linux Subsystem for Windows (using Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS). The system does correctly display a character when passing a literal to `%al`, and enters the subsequent dead loop.

```
.code16
.globl start

start:
cli
xorw %ax, %ax
movw %ax, %ds
movw %ax, %es
movw %ax, %ss

movb $0x0e, %ah
movb hello, %al
movb $0, %bh
movb $7, %bl
int $0x10

stop:
jmp stop

hello:
.string "Hello world."

.org 0x1fe
.word 0xAA55
```

I expect an output of `H` but all that is printed is `S`; it does not output anything at all in most other cases, unless a literal is used.

---

EDIT: Here is the disassembly of the binary using `objdump` after building:

```
bootsector.img:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <start>:
   0:    fa                       cli
   1:    31 c0                    xor    %eax,%eax
   3:    8e d8                    mov    %eax,%ds
   5:    8e c0                    mov    %eax,%es
   7:    8e d0                    mov    %eax,%ss
   9:    b4 0e                    mov    $0xe,%ah
   b:    a0 00 00 b7 00 b3 03     movabs 0x10cd03b300b70000,%al
  12:    cd 10 

0000000000000014 <stop>:
  14:    eb fe                    jmp    14 <stop>

0000000000000016 <hello>:
  16:    48                       rex.W
  17:    65 6c                    gs insb (%dx),%es:(%rdi)
  19:    6c                       insb   (%dx),%es:(%rdi)
  1a:    6f                       outsl  %ds:(%rsi),(%dx)
  1b:    20 77 6f                 and    %dh,0x6f(%rdi)
  1e:    72 6c                    jb     8c <hello+0x76>
  20:    64 2e 00 00              fs add %al,%cs:(%rax)
    ...
 1fc:    00 00                    add    %al,(%rax)
 1fe:    55                       push   %rbp
 1ff:    aa                       stos   %al,%es:(%rdi)
```

Steps I used to build and execute the code:

```
$ as bootsector.S -o bootsector.img
$ objcopy -O binary bootsector.img
$ qemu-system-i386 bootsector.img -curses
```

Comment: You're neglecting to set any segment registers (they need to match whatever address you're passing to the linker), and `movb %7, %bl` should be `movb $7, %bl`.

Comment: I've corrected that typo which was just from me rewriting my code, but it was not present while I was testing. I've updated my code to set the segment registers but it continues to fail. I'd like to reiterate that it does work when passing literals to ``%al``.

Comment: Good point, I guess I just assumed there was an `int $10` in there? @OP: `xorw %ax, %ds` isn't a legal instruction, I guess you mean `mov %ax, %ds`? But we still need to see how you're linking. You should show ALL of your code including how you assemble and create the binary. Also the program is short enough that you could include a hexdump/disassembly of the first couple of instructions.

Comment: I made a lot of mistakes rewriting the code, sorry. I fully corrected the code in the post, as well as included the disassembly.

Comment: @user3658679: How are you creating `bootsector.img`? Post the command line steps, and otherwise have a look at e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/32508919/786653

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are assembling your code to an object file and you are converting the object to a binary file directly. You need to add a linking process to produce an executable from the ELF object and have it converted to binary. The linking step also specifies the origin point of 0x7c00.

What you need to do is:

- Assemble the boot sector with AS (GNU assembler) to an ELF object. I recommend outputting as ELF32 instead of ELF64.
- Use LD (GNU Linker) to link the ELF object to an ELF executable or to a binary file directly. Use LD to specify an origin point of 0x7c00.
- Place the boot sector in an image file.

The commands you can use are:

```
as boot.s -o boot.o
ld -Ttext=0x7c00 --oformat=binary boot.o -o boot.bin
```

`boot.bin` should be the final binary and should be exactly 512 bytes. You would normally place the boot sector in a disk image but for test purposes you should be able to run it directly with QEMU with:

```
qemu-system-i386 -fda boot.bin
```

If you dump the binary file using 16-bit instruction decoding starting with an origin point of 0x7c00 with the command:

```
ndisasm -b16 -o 0x7c00 boot.bin
```

You should get output that is similar to:

> ```
> 00007C00  FA                cli
> 00007C01  31C0              xor ax,ax
> 00007C03  8ED8              mov ds,ax
> 00007C05  8EC0              mov es,ax
> 00007C07  8ED0              mov ss,ax
> 00007C09  B40E              mov ah,0xe
> 00007C0B  A0167C            mov al,[0x7c16]
> 00007C0E  B700              mov bh,0x0
> 00007C10  B307              mov bl,0x7
> 00007C12  CD10              int 0x10
> 00007C14  EBFE              jmp short 0x7c14
> 00007C16  48                dec ax
> 00007C17  656C              gs insb
> 00007C19  6C                insb
> 00007C1A  6F                outsw
> 00007C1B  20776F            and [bx+0x6f],dh
> 00007C1E  726C              jc 0x7c8c
> 00007C20  642E0000          add [cs:bx+si],al
> 00007C24  0000              add [bx+si],al
> 00007C26  0000              add [bx+si],al
> 00007C28  0000              add [bx+si],al
>
> [snip for brevity]
>
> 00007DFA  0000              add [bx+si],al
> 00007DFC  0000              add [bx+si],al
> 00007DFE  55                push bp
> 00007DFF  AA                stosb
> ```

---

### Alternative way to Build

You can also use AS to assemble to an object file, use LD to link to an ELF, and then use OBJCOPY to convert the ELF executable to a binary file. This also allows you to use the ELF executable for symbolic debugging using remote GDB etc. You can also use OBJDUMP instead of NDISASM to see the generated code.

The sequence of commands would be:

```
as boot.s -o boot.o
ld -Ttext=0x7c00 boot.o -o boot.elf
objcopy -O binary boot.elf boot.bin
```

Now you can use OBJDUMP to dump `boot.elf`. Be aware that you need to specify that you want to decode as 16-bit code. The OBJDUMP command would be:

```
objdump -Dx -Mi8086 boot.elf
```

The output would appear similar to this (if using a 64-bit toolchain as you appear to be using):

> ```
> boot.elf:     file format elf64-x86-64
> boot.elf
> architecture: i386:x86-64, flags 0x00000112:
> EXEC_P, HAS_SYMS, D_PAGED
> start address 0x0000000000007c00
>
> Program Header:
>     LOAD off    0x0000000000000000 vaddr 0x0000000000007000 paddr 0x0000000000007000 align 2**12
>          filesz 0x0000000000000e00 memsz 0x0000000000000e00 flags r-x
>     LOAD off    0x00000000000010e8 vaddr 0x00000000004000e8 paddr 0x00000000004000e8 align 2**12
>          filesz 0x0000000000000020 memsz 0x0000000000000020 flags r--
>     NOTE off    0x00000000000010e8 vaddr 0x00000000004000e8 paddr 0x00000000004000e8 align 2**3
>          filesz 0x0000000000000020 memsz 0x0000000000000020 flags r--
>
> Sections:
> Idx Name          Size      VMA               LMA               File off  Algn
>   0 .note.gnu.property 00000020  00000000004000e8  00000000004000e8  000010e8  2**3
>                   CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
>   1 .text         00000200  0000000000007c00  0000000000007c00  00000c00  2**0
>                   CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, CODE
> SYMBOL TABLE:
> 00000000004000e8 l    d  .note.gnu.property     0000000000000000 .note.gnu.property
> 0000000000007c00 l    d  .text  0000000000000000 .text
> 0000000000000000 l    df *ABS*  0000000000000000 boot.o
> 0000000000007c16 l       .text  0000000000000000 hello
> 0000000000007c14 l       .text  0000000000000000 stop
> 0000000000007c00 g       .text  0000000000000000 _start
> 0000000000008000 g       .text  0000000000000000 __bss_start
> 0000000000008000 g       .text  0000000000000000 _edata
> 0000000000008000 g       .text  0000000000000000 _end
>
>
>
> Disassembly of section .note.gnu.property:
>
> 00000000004000e8 <.note.gnu.property>:
>   4000e8:       04 00                   add    $0x0,%al
>   4000ea:       00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
>   4000ec:       10 00                   adc    %al,(%rax)
>   4000ee:       00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
>   4000f0:       05 00 00 00 47          add    $0x47000000,%eax
>   4000f5:       4e 55                   rex.WRX push %rbp
>   4000f7:       00 01                   add    %al,(%rcx)
>   4000f9:       00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
>   4000fb:       c0 04 00 00             rolb   $0x0,(%rax,%rax,1)
>   4000ff:       00 01                   add    %al,(%rcx)
>   400101:       00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
>   400103:       00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
>   400105:       00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
>         ...
>
> Disassembly of section .text:
>
> 0000000000007c00 <_start>:
>     7c00:       fa                      cli
>     7c01:       31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
>     7c03:       8e d8                   mov    %eax,%ds
>     7c05:       8e c0                   mov    %eax,%es
>     7c07:       8e d0                   mov    %eax,%ss
>     7c09:       b4 0e                   mov    $0xe,%ah
>     7c0b:       a0 16 7c b7 00 b3 07    movabs 0x10cd07b300b77c16,%al
>     7c12:       cd 10
>
> 0000000000007c14 <stop>:
>     7c14:       eb fe                   jmp    7c14 <stop>
>
> 0000000000007c16 <hello>:
>     7c16:       48                      rex.W
>     7c17:       65 6c                   gs insb (%dx),%es:(%rdi)
>     7c19:       6c                      insb   (%dx),%es:(%rdi)
>     7c1a:       6f                      outsl  %ds:(%rsi),(%dx)
>     7c1b:       20 77 6f                and    %dh,0x6f(%rdi)
>     7c1e:       72 6c                   jb     7c8c <hello+0x76>
>     7c20:       64 2e 00 00             fs add %al,%cs:(%rax)
>         ...
>     7dfc:       00 00                   add    %al,(%rax)
>     7dfe:       55                      push   %rbp
>     7dff:       aa                      stos   %al,%es:(%rdi)
> ```

---

### Observations

You may be curious to know why in your output you got strange `movabs` instruction:

> ```
> bootsector.img:     file format elf64-x86-64
>
> Disassembly of section .text:
>
> 0000000000000000 <start>:
>    0:    fa                       cli
>    1:    31 c0                    xor    %eax,%eax
>    3:    8e d8                    mov    %eax,%ds
>    5:    8e c0                    mov    %eax,%es
>    7:    8e d0                    mov    %eax,%ss
>    9:    b4 0e                    mov    $0xe,%ah
>    b:    a0 00 00 b7 00 b3 03     movabs 0x10cd03b300b70000,%al
>   12:    cd 10
> ```

OBJDUMP doesn't know that the code is 16-bit (that information isn't retained in an ELF object file). OBJDUMP defaulted to 64-bit decoding because the object file format was `elf64-x86-64` (ELF64). By default AS on a 64-bit toolchain produced 64-bit objects. OBJDUMP will default to 64-bit decoding of ELF64 files and that was what gives the incorrect decoding. You can use `-Mi8086` to request 16-bit decoding with OBJDUMP.

---

### Other Recommendations

- Consider renaming `start` to `_start` to keep the linker from giving a warning about not being able to find the entry point. The warning isn't fatal and can be ignored.  The alternative is to tell LD that the entry point is `start` by adding the extra option `--entry=start`. The command could look like:

  ```
  ld -Ttext=0x7c00 --entry=start boot.o -o boot.elf
  ```

Comment: Thank you, I was missing the step of linking the AS output to an ELF file and specifying the origin point. :)